# Issue with environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, sudo

Please help me running below command from user2 account. I cannot figure out what's the issue with this.

```
[user2@localhost bin]# sudo -u user1 /opt/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
[user2@localhost bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/Java_7
```

Entry for user2 in sudoers file is as below :

```
%user2 ALL=(user1) NOPASSWD:/opt/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh,/opt/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

However the environment variables are set. I run the same script with root user and it works fine.

```
[root@localhost bin]# /opt/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/Tomcat/
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/Tomcat/
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/Tomcat//temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/Java_7
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/Tomcat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/Tomcat//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

I have checked it further. JAVA_HOME is set for both the users.

```
[root@localhost bin]# pwd
/opt/Tomcat/bin
[root@localhost bin]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/Java_7
[root@localhost bin]# su user1
[user1@localhost bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/Java_7
[user1@localhost bin]$ exit
[root@localhost bin]# su user2
[user2@localhost bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/Java_7

[user2@localhost bin]$ ps aux | grep java
user1     47066  0.1 10.9 1004608 77364 pts/2   Sl   Jun12   0:15 /opt/Java_7/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/Tomcat//conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/Tomcat//endorsed -classpath /opt/Tomcat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/Tomcat//bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/Tomcat/ -Dcatalina.home=/opt/Tomcat/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/Tomcat//temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
user2     49318  0.0  0.1 103240   840 pts/2    S+   02:11   0:00 grep java

[user2@localhost bin]$ sudo -u user1 /opt/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

Comment: That Conversation should rather be held here. Please check if you can run it when you log in as a different user, it's just for locating the problem. Also, try to use sudo -u user1 to echo your environment variable, see if that's different from when you actually log in as that user.

Comment: Yes. I can run the it when i log in as user1.
After adding the command in sudoers file for echoing variables , i am able to echo $JAVA_HOME. And it gives the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the JAVA_HOME environment variable when using sudo, you should add `Defaults env_keep +="JAVA_HOME"` to your sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sudo -u user1`, then neither the JAVA_HOME path of user2, nor the path of root will be used, you will need to set the JAVA_HOME path of user1. From the way it looks, you did not set the JAVA_HOME path of user1

Comment: I have checked. JAVA_HOME is set for both the users.

Comment: Does the error persist when you use "sudo -u user1 -E"? Also, can you log in as user1 and run the command without sudo?

Comment: when i run the command with `-E` it says: `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment`. And this command should be run as sudo because we need to distribute these users to different teams(if it works) so that they have limitations.